# Take $elements variable and narrow down attr is equal to x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable `$element`.

This selector can be equal to many different elements on the page. How can I further narrow down this element based on whether it's attribute is equal to another?

I know you can do this `$("div[attr=x]");`. But I want to be able to further narrow down this already set variable for efficiency.

Comment: Your question makes no sense in it's current form.

Comment: How so? Do you know jQuery?

Comment: Yes I do. It just worded in a way that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JordanS Let me try again. I have this selector element. It is currently selecting all of the divs on my page. I want it to select the div with an attribute equal to a certain value.

Comment: I could use div[attr=val]. But I would like to use the $element. Like $element[attr=val]

Comment: @JordanS Does that make more sense?

Comment: So you want to refine your selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get at jQuery's [filter function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). You can make a selection, then further refine that selection as demonstrated.

```js
// First make a big selection
var elements = $(".a");
// Filter your selection to just the div with the 'c' class.
elements.filter(".c").css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

```css
.a {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a c"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```